# calling quit() method of QApplication

Tags: qt

if i try to use quit() method directly, it is compiling perfectly,
however during runtime there comes an error saying "Object::connect: No such slot myClass::quit()."
so to avoid this, is there any way?
by using a method quitPicture()(defined as slot) the application is working fine.
is this the only solution?

```
myClass::myClass(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QWidget *window = new QWidget;
    window->setWindowTitle(QObject::tr("Class"));

    QPushButton *quitButton = new QPushButton("&Quit");
//    QObject::connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(quit()));      //showing run time error
    QObject::connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(quitPicture())); //working perfectly

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(this);
    layout->addWidget(quitButton);
    window->setLayout(layout);
    window->show();
}

void myClass::quitPicture()
{
    std::cout << "calling quitPicture" << std::endl;
    QApplication::quit();
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The button's `clicked` signal can be connected directly to the application's `quit` slot:

```
QObject::connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                 QApplication::instance(), SLOT(quit()));
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer covers new signal/slot syntax in Qt and also additionally covers how to handle it when using a signal that uses overloads.

For signals with no overloads using QObject as an example object:

```
QObject obj(nullptr); 

QObject::connect(&obj, &QObject::destroyed, QCoreApplication::instance(), \
 &QCoreApplication::quit);
```

For signals with overloads using QProcess as an example object:

```
QProcess * process = new QProcess(QCoreApplication::instance());

QObject::connect(process, static_cast<void (QProcess::*)(int)>(&QProcess::finished), \
                     QCoreApplication::instance(), &QCoreApplication::quit);
```

That crazy-looking syntax is basically this, as placeholder syntax:

```
static_cast< _signalReturnType_( _ObjectName::*_ )( _overloadType1_, _overloadType2_, \
…etc )>( _&ObjectName::signalName_ )
```

You can check out [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions) if you want the details on why.

Since QProcess has two overloads, this is the other overload for it:

```
QProcess * process = new QProcess(QCoreApplication::instance());

QObject::connect(process, static_cast<void (QProcess::*)(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)>( \
 &QProcess::finished ), QCoreApplication::instance(), &QCoreApplication::quit);
```

If this crazy-looking stuff is spinning your head, don't sweat it. You can comment questions here, as I usually check SO daily, or at least nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

```
void my_exit_func()
{
    // in mainwindow.cpp
    delete MainWindow;
}
```