# Native Qt signal is not callable in PyCharm

Tags: qt, signals, pycharm

I created a `QMainWindow` with menu and tools :

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
```

Then, I created a `quit` action by shortcut :

```
    def initUI(self):
        exitaction=QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit.png'),'&Exit',self)
        exitaction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitaction.setStatusTip('EXIT application')
```

Now : `pycharm` tells me it can't find reference `qApp` in `__init__.py` :

```
        exitaction.triggered().connect(QtGui.qApp.quit)
        self.statusBar()
        menubar=self.menuBar()
        fileMenu=menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitaction)
        self.setGeometry(300,300,250,150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Menubar')
        self.show()
def main():
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex=Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use QApplication istead of QtGui.qapp:

`exitaction.triggered().connect(QApplication.instance().quit)`

Compare the answer to: [calling quit() method of QApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040988/calling-quit-method-of-qapplication)